# ¿Como puedo visualizar los registros de una base de datos en Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby, heroku, hosting

Luego de hacer `deploy` a mi aplicación, ¿como puedo ver los registros de las tablas de la BD `postgresql` en `Heroku`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas a necesitar algún cliente de postgres ya sea [pgadmin3](https://pgadmin.org/download/windows.php) o [postico](http://eggerapps.at/postico).

En [esta](https://data.heroku.com/) página de heroku seleccionas la base de datos que quieres conectarte y luego busca donde dice "Database Credentials" da click en "Get credentials for manual connections to this database"

Obtendrás los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En pgadmin3 cuando crees una nueva coneccion en propiedades pones los datos obtenidos anteriormente, recuerda poner el nombre de la Database en Maintenance DB y quitar postgres (asi me funciono a mi.).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres conectarte por medio de la linea de comandos, lo hice con el siguiente comando en mac o linux:

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL --app NOMBRE
```

no olvides cambiar NOMBRE por el nombre de tu app.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conectarte a la base de datos mediante alguna herramienta local dependiendo del sistema operativo, en el panel de control de heroku puedes encontrar los accesos remotos para la base de datos.

Aqui te dejo la documentacion oficial sobre tu pregunta

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku

Tambien puedes probar hacer una conexión via túnel ssh al servidor heroku y desde ahi conectarte a la base de datos de igual manera usando un cliente local.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Joel Ibaceta, voy a revisar el link ¿conoces alguna herramienta para Ubuntu?

Comment: Esta es buena https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/pgadmin3/

Comment: Me está dando algunos problemas, luego continuo con esto y te comento @Joel Ibaceta

Comment: si tienes mac puedes usar la app postico (https://eggerapps.at/postico/) está mucho mejor que pgadmin.

Comment: Muchas gracias @roselux, en particular me funcionó con `heroku pg:psql` sin nada mas (entono Ubuntu).

Comment: Igualmente creo que la respuesta de @Joel Ibaceta está buena, pero me tuve problemas con la instalación, por lo tanto voy a votara como útil. Gracias nuevamente.